# Why is LaTeX pronounced "Lay-Tek"?

Tags: latex-misc

My friend who recently introduced me to LaTeX always pronounced it "Lay-Tek". Is he wrong? assuming he isn't why is LaTeX pronounced this way when it clearly has nothing to with the X at the end?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX#Pronouncing_and_writing_%22LaTeX%22

Comment: according to DEK, the correct pronounciation makes you spit on your computer screen.